# State-space model with mean-reverting coefficients

Tags: r, regression, time-series, state-space-models

I am trying to estimate a state-space model with time-varying coefficients. I do plan to include multiple regressors in the model, but for simplicity let's assume that there is only one explanatory variable. The observation equation is:
$$
y_{t} = \beta_{0,t} + \beta_{1,t}X_{t} + \epsilon_{t}
$$
I would like to impose a mean-reverting restriction on the coefficient $\beta_{1}$ so that it follows an AR(1)-process with non-zero mean $c$, while $\beta_{0}$ is just an ordinary AR(1) :
$$
\beta_{0,t} = \alpha\beta_{0,t-1}+\eta_{0,t}, |\alpha|<1
$$
$$
\beta_{1,t} = c + \rho\beta_{1,t-1}+\eta_{1,t}, |\rho|<1
$$
However, I have trouble formulating the model for `KFAS`  package in R. I understand that the transition matrix $T$ should have NA's on its main diagonal to estimate $\alpha$ and $\rho$, but I cannot figure out how to include a constant term into $\beta_{1,t}$ as well. I would also like to estimate the variance of $\eta_{0,t}$ and $\eta_{1,t}$ in the model (thus, I need help formulating the $R$ and $Q$ matrices as well).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you miss indices at right hand sides: in the 1-st equation $\beta_{t-1}$ is $\beta_{0,t-1}$ and similarly for the 2-nd.

Comment: @Yves true, thanks for noting that, edited the question